# kubectl get deployments output differ from this in documentation

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I run this command

```
kubectl get deployments
```

at my Linux Ubuntu 18 machine, I got different output than expected (according to documentation).

Expected:
[image]

Actual:

[image]

Of course, I am not talking about values, I am talking about names of labels.

[EDIT]

My k8s version:
[image]

Comment: can you run, please, kubectl version and paste in the question the output?

Comment: you get the same info tho, in your case is `ready 0/3`

Comment: @prometherion sorry, should have done that initially.

Comment: @Federkun are you sure about that? I mean, CURRENT label shows the number of running pods inside deployment. If I am changing something in deployment configuration and my 'old' pods are being shut down, but still exist, there might be a situation I have, for example, 7 current pods, but desired would be, for example 5. IMO, which can be totally misleading, READY wouldn't be able expose/describe such a situation. It would show only new pods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an old output format. The newer output you're getting below contains all the same information; the "READY" field is a combination of the old "DESIRED" and "CURRENT".

It's showing as `4/5` in your output to indicate 4 pods ready/current, and 5 pods desired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Kubernetes is such a large and highly active project, so there's always going to be more to do, and cases like this. If you're interested in contributing, maybe to the docs for this case in point, opening an issue for this particular case, or even raising a PR to fix it, here's a nice introduction guide to get you started https://kubernetes.io/docs/contribute/start/

Answer (score 1):

The output depends on client version. Let's check it with the same server

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:36:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubectl get deployments kube-dns -n kube-system
NAME       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-dns   2         2         2            2           10d
```

Switching the kubectl version changes output:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:44:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:36:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

$ kubectl get deployments kube-dns -n kube-system
NAME       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-dns   2/2     2            2           10d
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears a lot. I am just wondering why k8s docs cover old version... I approved cewood answer because he was faster, but your answer is great too.